# Opposite of not() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question, I've the following lines which equals to **not active links**:

```
$links.not($active).each(function() 
{
     //Do sth...
});
```

what is the opposite of the `.not(...)` function in JavaScript? because I need to know the active links, Any ideas !?

Comment: I think you want `.filter()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `$links.not($active)` creates a collection with the elements from `$links` except the elements in `$active`.

To get the active links, just use the `$active` object:

```
$active.each(function() 
{
  //Do sth...
});
```

Answer (score 9):

This is jQuery, not JavaScript. The opposite of `.not` is [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `.filter()`, which returns a subset that only includes matching elements.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of `not` in programming is often named `is`

http://api.jquery.com/is/

However this will return boolean true of false so in your case you'll be wanting `filter`

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

**Example:**

```
$links.filter('.onlyThisClass').each(function() 
{
     //Do sth...
});
```

Comment: No, the `not` method excludes elements and returns a new jQuery object, the `is` method checks if there are any matching elements and returns a boolean.

Comment: @guffa that's not what he said, unless he's modified it since your comment.

Comment: @KevinB I had modified my post for clarification